# what is the minimum memory required for executing mldeploy in marklogic

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am running mldeploy in VM is having 3GB memory but it is failing due to insufficient memory.What is the minimum memory required to run mldeploy in marklogic or if there is any settings allow to run ml deploy in 3GB memory

Answer (score 2):

This is a function of the memory required by Gradle and the JVM that it runs in, along with the memory consumed by the ml-gradle plugin itself. By default, Gradle runs in "daemon" mode - you can find out more information at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html , including information on understanding how much memory Gradle is consuming.

3GB is on the low side - I can't remember the last time I used a JVM-based development tool like Gradle on a machine with less than 8GB. I'd want to guess that 4GB should suffice, but I don't know, and there's also the matter of what else is running within your VM and consuming memory.